# Bluetooth chat timeout connection error

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have only one paired device in my application. When I try to make a connection between 2 devices, for few seconds it gets connected .
    But after that it gets disconnected .

```
Logcat shows this error:

Socket Type: nullaccept() failed
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```